# Kendo UI MVC Send MultiSelect data values to Action method

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The Kendo UI Ajax Binding documentation at [Ajax Binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-action-method) describes passing multiple data parameters to an Action method but it does not address passing arrays like MultiSelect values.

In the example below, if multisel is set to a string like "237896", the controller receives sitesFilter="237896". But if multisel is set to the MultiSelect value as shown below, the controller receives sitesFilter = null.

What is the proper way to send all of the MultiSelect values to the Action method using the MVC wrapper?

```
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                              .Ajax()
                              .ServerOperation(false)
                              .Read(read => read.Action("Documents_Read", "Document")
                                                .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                                                .Data("getCriteria"))

    function getCriteria() {
    var multisel = $("#sites").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
    return {
        sitesFilter: multisel
    };
}

    public ActionResult Documents_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string sitesFilter=null)
    {
        return Json(GetDocuments(sitesFilter).ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

EDIT: getCriteria should convert the data to a string as shown below:

```
 function getCriteria() {
        var multisel = $("#sites").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString();
        return {
            sitesFilter: multisel
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution doesn't use Ajax, but describes the transmission of multiselected values to the Controller in general! Ajaxify it, Model transmission should work similarly!

**.cshtml Filter View:** form with selection fields to POST the chosen values to the Controller. *Model.Products* is a *List* of Type *Product* with properties *ID* and *DisplayName*.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @{
        IEnumerable<Product> productSelectList = Model.Products;
        Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.ProductIds)
            .BindTo(new SelectList(productSelectList, "ID", "DisplayName"))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px;" })
            .Render();    
    }
</div>
```

**Controller.cs:** Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchForLicenseTerm(SearchLicenseTermFilterViewModel searchLicenseTermFilterViewModel)
{
    // Search logic
}
```

**Model.cs:** specific Model used

```
public class SearchLicenseTermFilterViewModel
{
    public SearchLicenseTermFilterViewModel()
    {
        ProductIds = new List<Guid?>();
    }        
    public List<Guid?> ProductIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Received POST data in the Controller Action .jpeg:** You are seeing the filled List of GUIDs of the select entries from the Kendo.MultiSelect

[image]

Comment: Florian - Thanks. My problem was solved by converting the multiselect data value to string.

Comment: <3 This one saved my bacon <3

Comment: "Received POST data in the Controller Action .jpeg:" is this suppose to be an image?   Can you display how you post your data?

Answer (score 2):

var multisel = $("#sites").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(); was not being converted to a string.

var multisel = $("#sites").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().toString(); solved the problem.